# regex for string

Tags: regex, string

From the string I need received result like below (using regex).

string: `[Raxy] GTS_R-1/GTS_CNF-1/NA-15/SDA-1/MGTS-8002/PQM-1/APM-1/RF-3/NTL-15`

result: `[Raxy] MGTS-8002/PQM-1/APM-1`

I know how to get:

```
"[Raxy] " -> \[.+\][\s?]

"MGTS-8002/PQM-1/APM-1" -> MGTS-\d+/PQM-\d+/PQM-\d+/APM-\d+
```

but I have a problem how to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/^(\[[^\]\[]+]).*\/(MGTS-\d+\/PQM-\d+\/APM-\d+)/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/qUqFUf/2). Extract captures from the match, and combine into a single string.

Here is a brief demo:

```js
const string = "[Raxy] GTS_R-1/GTS_CNF-1/NA-15/SDA-1/MGTS-8002/PQM-1/APM-1/RF-3/NTL-15";
const match = /^(\[[^\]\[]+]).*\/(MGTS-\d+\/PQM-\d+\/APM-\d+)/.exec(string);
console.log(match[1] + " " + match[2]);
```